Changing incoming packet TTL on MacOS
Is there a way to change the incoming packet TTL on MacOS?  It appears using pfctl, but I cannot seem to figure out the syntax.  From reading the docs, something like reassemble tcp reassemble-tcp ttl 64.

What problem is solved by the changing of the TTL on a packet you have already received?

I am using Internet Sharing and the packet I receive has a low TTL.
